# Algorithm project issue

Tags: algorithm, binary, project, computer-science

I am studying computer science & project management online at the moment however I am really stuck on one algorithm project.
I have included all the inform required and also my project so far.
Maybe I have chosen he wrong algorithm?
Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

---

**Activity**

You are required to write a report on the following algorithm problem:
This problem asks you to find one false coin among a set of true coins. The false coin can be found because it doesn't weigh
the same as the rest of the true coins. It is either lighter or heavier, but you do not know in advance. The only method you
have to make a decision is a classic balance scale with two trays. You can put one or more coins on one tray, a similar number
on the other tray, and determine which tray has the lighter pile. For instance if you only have three coins then take coin 1 and
coin 2 and weigh them. If the scale balances, then coin 3 must be the odd one out. If the scale doesn't balance, then compare
coin 1 and coin 3. If they balance then coin 2 must be the odd one out, while if they don't then coin 1 must be the odd one
out.
The key to the problem is to find the false coin using the fewest number of comparisons. What is the fewest comparisons for 3
coins? For 4 coins? For 5 coins? For 12 coins? For N, an arbitrary number of coins? This problem is traditionally stated with 12
coins.

**Include the following in your report:**

- Understand the problem: Describe how you worked with the problem and examples to develop an understanding.
- Get an idea of how an algorithmic procedure might solve the problem: Describe one or more general approaches to solving the problem, including how you got your foot in the door.
- Formulate the algorithm: Describe your algorithm in more detail.
- Evaluate your algorithm for accuracy and for its potential as a tool for solving other problems: Describe why you think
  your algorithmic solution is correct and why it might be better than other ideas you had.

**My report so far:**

> **Algorithm Design**
>
> Problem:
>
> Find one false coin among a set of true coins
>   We are informed there are 12 coins in which we need to determine which coin is false.
>   We are also given a deeper insight about the false coin which is this coin will not weigh the same as the others. This will indicate to us that the coin is either heavier or lighter which is something we will have to determine.
>   Finally we are aware that we will have to make this determination with 2 tray scales.
>
> Solution:
>
> My first thoughts are, we are given an even number of coins which at the moments looks to me as an advantage.
>   From here I can place an even number of 6 coins on each tray. 
>   One of the trays will way more than the other however this does not define with tray still has the false coin as we are not sure if it is lighter or heavier in weight.
>   When I landed at this realisation, I realised the Binary Algorithm approach would not work in this situation as delving into the middle of the problem first will not make any determinations.

---

**Second Thought**

I could divide the coins into 2 separate groups again, each with a number of 6.
From here I can take 1 coin from pile 1 and 1 coin from pile 2.
If they both weight the same, neither coins are false and can be removed from the scale.
If 1 coin weighs more, we know that one of these coins are false.
Now we need to determine which one it is.
We can remove one coin and replace with the next coin. 
We know the next or last coin is true therefore if they balance, then the removed coin is false, and if 
they do not balance, we then know that the remaining coin is the false coin.
Now I will need to work out if this method is the best one to go with by working out the best, worst 
and average case scenario.
The worst case would be if all coins weigh the same until we get to the final 2 coins.

**We will divide into steps:**

- First the split down the middle `(1)`
- Next compare coin 1 to coin 2 `(2)`
- Next compare coin 3 to coin 4 `(3)`
- Next compare coin 5 to coin 6 (Unbalance occurs here) `(4)`
  Remove coin 5 & swap with coin 4

If balanced,
Then coin 6 is false
Else coin 5 is false
`Lg n = 12 = 4`

Comment: The current draft of your report omits mention of your recourse to Stack Overflow for advice. I believe that a lot of educational institutions frown upon unattributed use of references so don't forget to include attribution.

Comment: Here you only check 6 coins (not 12)! But even if you fix it, be aware that its complexity is `O(n)` and not `lg(n)` since you need up to `(n/2) + 1` comparisons to find the fake coin. Thus, my method has a better complexity.

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm to solve your problem is to follow this procedure:

- Split your stack in halves.
- Split again one half and put it on the balance.
- If this half contains the fake coin, the result will be imbalanced. So you can just pick the right half...
- Repeat the procedure until you have only 2 or 3 coins.
- Then, you can find the good coin using 2 comparisons.

Thus, assuming you have n coins you'll need `int(log2(n)) + 2` comparisons to find it.

I didn't check the optimality of this approach but it must be at least  close to optimality (1 or 2 extra comparisons at most).